# Why are my Developer Tools always scaled up when I start Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

In my Chrome browser on one computer, the Developer Tools are zoomed to a larger font size, and I can't (permanently) set it back to normal!

After opening a fresh instance of the browser and going to a normal page (eg. Google home page), the browser looks fine.  However, when I open the Developer Tools panel, that panel is zoomed in so that the font is large.  I can click into the panel and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to return it to a normal size.  But when I close and reopen Chrome, it is back to the zoomed size again.  This has been a problem for a few months, over multiple versions.

How can I permanently set the zoom in the Developer Tools panel back to normal?

```
Chrome Version: 23.0.1271.22 beta-m
OS: Windows 7, 64bit
```

**Edit:**

I've found that using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> seem to be effective between sessions, but NOT when it is first opened.  So, I'm currently at a +2 zoom when I open the Developer Tools.  If I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> once, I go to +3.  If I then restart the browser, my Developer Tools appears again at +2, but pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> puts me to +4.  Similarly, if I presss <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> twice, I see it at 0 zoom. When I reopen the browser, it shows as +2 zoom again, but pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> once takes me to +1 (since it somehow thinks it is at 0 zoom).  Confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

1. Close all Chrome windows
2. Edit the `Preferences` file in your Google Chrome profile.

   On Linux this is `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences`; on Windows it will be in `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` (or possibly `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`))
3. Locate the setting `"per_host_zoom_levels"`
4. Remove the line that starts with `"devtools"`. This was set to -1 in my profile (my inspector was zoomed out by default).

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit old, but might get you going in the right direction:

http://blog.dotsmart.net/2011/09/30/change-font-size-in-chrome-devtools/

To summarize, there is a custom.css that drives this, and you are only temporarily overriding it when you press Ctrl-0 which is why it returns back after reopening Chrome.

Edit: After reading through the comments on that page, I learned that <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> will zoom/unzoom the developer tools. Using this method, the settings were retained across Chrome sessions (at least for me on version 22)

Comment: As per the article, I found my custom.css file... and it is empty.

Comment: Did you try Ctrl + and Ctrl - ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried Ctrl + and Ctrl - and Ctrl 0.  All work as expected, but when I reopen the browser, it is back to the same zoom level as before.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have zooming issue on Developer tools. Try to press Ctrl+0 to set zoom level to 100%. Home this will help.

Comment: He already mentioned that this does not permanently fix the issue.